# Calculate the intercept and coefficient in Logistic Regression by hand (manually)

Tags: regression, logistic

I have a dataset as below [image: Dataset]. This is for predicting for the patient after taking the Rizatriptan (medicine) whether the they can relief the pain (stop headache) or not (Yes/No). By using spss, we can find the b0 = -2.490 and b1= 0.165[image: Intercept and Coefficient]. I want to know the way how we can calculate to find b0 and b1 by mathematics or by hand. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you tread dose as continuous than the estimation necessarily involves an iterative algorithm. However, if you include dose as a categorical variable, then you have a so called saturated model, whose coefficients have a closed form solution. Here is an example using Stata:

```
. // enter the data
. clear

. input dose relieved freq

          dose   relieved       freq
  1.       0    0         65
  2.       0    1          2
  3.       25   0         68
  4.       25   1          7
  5.       50   0        101
  6.       50   1         29
  7.       100  0        105
  8.       100  1         40
  9. end

.
. // estimate the model, and display the results as odds ratios
. logit relieved i.dose [fw=freq], or nolog

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =        417
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      28.59
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -186.66276                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0711

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    relieved | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        dose |
         25  |   3.345588   2.744499     1.47   0.141     .6701979    16.70098
         50  |   9.331683   6.981748     2.99   0.003     2.153331    40.43981
        100  |   12.38095   9.181196     3.39   0.001     2.894267    52.96262
             |
       _cons |   .0307692   .0220893    -4.85   0.000     .0075342    .1256599
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.
. // the exp(constant) is the odds of relieved for the baseline category:
. di 2/65       //  odds of relieved with 0 dose
.03076923

.
. // the exp(coefficient) is the odds ratio, i.e. a ratio of odds:
. di (7/68)  /  /// odds of relieved with 2.5 dose
>    (2/65)     //  odds of relieved with 0 dose
3.3455882

.
. // estimate the model, and display the results as raw coefficients
. logit relieved i.dose [fw=freq], nolog

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =        417
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      28.59
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -186.66276                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0711

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    relieved |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        dose |
         25  |   1.207643   .8203339     1.47   0.141    -.4001823    2.815467
         50  |   2.233415   .7481767     2.99   0.003      .767016    3.699815
        100  |   2.516159   .7415581     3.39   0.001     1.062732    3.969586
             |
       _cons |   -3.48124   .7179029    -4.85   0.000    -4.888304   -2.074176
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.
. // the constant is the ln(odds) of relieved for the baseline category:
. di ln(2/65)       //  odds of relieved with 0 dose
-3.4812401

.
. // the coefficient is the ln(odds ratio), i.e. the logarithm of a ratio of odds:
. di ln((7/68)  /  /// odds of relieved with 2.5 dose
>       (2/65))    //  odds of relieved with 0 dose
1.2076425
```

Comment: 1) What is the iterative algorithm? (not the name of the algorithm, give the actual process) 2) What is that closed form solution?

Comment: @Mitch read any book on logistic regression